# Prevent global hyphenation for a specific word

Tags: hyphenation

I know this is a common question.

I want to stop LaTeX splitting the word "Byte".

I already searched for the problem and found the solution with `\hyphenation`.

I thought `\hyphenation{Byte}` would solve my problem. But unfortunately it doesn't work. I think it has something to do that he probably just uses this for "byte" and not for words that contain it (German example: "Bytestrom", LaTeX splits it  By-testrom).

The second solution which I found was using `\mbox` with `\newcommand`. I don't like this solution very much.

So my questions are:

- Why does `\hyphenation{byte}` not work?
- Is there another way to solve my problem?

---

Example added by Jake:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\begin{document}
Trying to determine how a special word is hyphenated: Bytestrom.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. You can highlight code by using the backtick character. Enjoy your stay here! :)

Comment: LaTeX should not split a word that is 4 letters long. There must be something else wrong. Please, provide a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: (Sorry, I misread the question)

Comment: I think you gave the answer to your first question already yourself: the `\hyphenation` command does not expand its arguments to longer words that contain a word defined in `\hyphenation`. Unfortunately I don't have any answer to your second question.

Comment: To answer your first question: the command `\hyphenation` applies to complete words only.  It is designed for English, which does not  have compound words in the abundance found in German.

Comment: @AndrewSwann -- don't confuse this with english.  the english hyphenation is correct for "byte-wise", "byte-stream", and "Byte-strom".  this has to be fixed in the german hyphenation patterns. i've written to the tex-hyphen list and asked for that to be done.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was thinking more of the general design of the hyphenation scheme, rather than specific hyphenation for this word.

Comment: @AndrewSwann -- understood, but what i was trying to point out is that, with proper hyphenation patterns for german, the problem would go away globally.  i'm not sure how the german patterns are derived, but if `patgen` is used, all that is necessary is to add a couple of representative words with appropriate hyphenation points marked.  david carlisle's answer gives some detailed information on what an appropriate pattern should look like.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Agreed; adding this to german patterns is a good idea.

Answer (score 15):

Quoting the *TeXbook*, p. 452:

> ```
> \hyphenation{man-u-script man-u-scripts ap-pen-dix}
> ```
>
> [...] tells TeX how to hypenate the words 'manuscript' , 'manuscripts', and 'appendix'. Notice that both singular and plural forms of 'manuscript' were entered, since the exception dictionary affects hyphenation only when a word agrees completely with an exceptional entry.

In other words, the answer to your question is to enter both `Byte` and `Byte-strom` into the exception list.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\hyphenation{Byte Byte-strom}
\begin{document}
Trying to determine how a special word is hyphenated: Bytestrom.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. As Benedikt Bauer said, this would mean, that i have to go through the text and find every word that contains this (and also repeat this for similar problems). I thought there is maybe an easier solution.

Comment: With any capable text editor, searching for "byte" shouldn't be too  onerous.

Answer (score 9):

There is a way to solve the problem, but it is not for the faint hearted. `\hyphenation` is designed for minor corrections to the global rules, for specific words. You however want to change the global rules, and for that you need `\patterns` not `\hyphenation`.

`\patterns` may only be used at initex time when making a format and reads a patterns list that looks something like

```
% dehyphn-x-2012-05-30.pat

\message{German Hyphenation Patterns (Reformed Orthography, 2006) `dehyphn-x' 2012-05-30 (WL)}

% TeX-Trennmuster für die reformierte (2006) deutsche Rechtschreibung
%
%
% Copyright (C) 2007, 2008, 2009, 2011, 2012 Werner Lemberg <wl@gnu.org>
%
% This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
% of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN
% archives in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt; either
% version 1 of the License, or any later version.
%
%
% The word list is available from
%
%   http://repo.or.cz/w/wortliste.git?a=commit;h=7915938d035684993f8c363729f963eec71c85b1
%
% The used patgen parameters are
%
%   1 1 | 2 5 | 1 1 1
%   2 2 | 2 5 | 1 2 1
%   3 3 | 2 6 | 1 1 1
%   4 4 | 2 6 | 1 4 1
%   5 5 | 2 7 | 1 1 1
%   6 6 | 2 7 | 1 6 1
%   7 7 | 2 13 | 1 4 1
%   8 8 | 2 13 | 1 8 1

\patterns{%
.ab1a
.abi4
.ab3l
.abo2
.ab3ol
.ab1or
.ack2
.ag4n
.ag4r
...
```

As you may guess these things are normally constructed mechanically (traditionally using the `patgen` program)

The TeXBook says

> ...since patterns are supposed to be prepared by experts who are paid
>   well for their expertise....

However you want to change the hyphenation of words beginning with byte so if you change the name of the file as required by LPPL You can probably add a pattern of the form

```
.b4y4t4e
```

where `.` denotes the beginning of the word and the numbers between letters encourage (odd) or discourage (even)  hyphenation.

Note I haven't tested this and I haven't actually used the `\pattern` command this millennium. But something like this would probably work.

Answer (score 5):

```
\hyphenation{Byte-strom}
```

works as expected. `\hyphenation{Byte}` refers only to the single word Byte, You can try a setting like

```
\AtBeginDocument{\lefthyphenmin=3}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: But his Problem is that @JustCoding is using a whole bunch of words that are combined from the word "byte" and some additional words (a quite common thing in german). Therefore it would be necessary to add a hyphenation pattern for every combination. It would of course be much nicer if one could just say something like "never hyphenate any word containing 'byte' between 'y' and 't'". Of course this could have some unwanted side effects.

Comment: @BenediktBauer The word "Derbytermin" *should* be hyphenated between "y" and "t". :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I meant with "unwanted side effects", I just couldn't find an example while writing my comment ;-)

Comment: a simple solution in this special case is: `\AtBeginDocument{\lefthyphenmin=3}` in the preamble and Byte maybe not hyphenated. However, Byte is an english word and a hyphenation in german between t and e is possible!

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\lefthyphenmin=3}` is a bad idea for German texts IMO because it will prevent hyphenation after common prefixes like "Ab" and "Zu".

Comment: Hello Herbert, thanks for your idea. But \lefthyphenmin is a bit too global, since it affects all other words too.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments.

- The correct left and right hyphen minimum values for German are 2.  Setting `\lefthyphenmin` to 3, however, is a very good idea, except for typesetting in very small columns.  While some prefixes like »ab« and »zu« are indeed skipped then, it improves the global layout usually.
- If you use the experimental German hyphenation patterns for the post-1996 hyphenation rules, »Bytestrom« gets correctly hyphenated as »Byte-strom«:

  ```
  \RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

  \begin{document}
  \showhyphens{Bytestrom}
  \end{document}
  ```

  You can find more details in the documentation of the [`dehyph-exptl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dehyph-exptl) package.
- The experimental patterns for the pre-1996 rules don't hyphenate »Bytestrom« at all, which is incorrect but better than the original patterns.  Reason is that this very word is missing in the word list.
- The [»wortliste« project](http://repo.or.cz/w/wortliste.git) comes with Makefiles which simplifies the creation of new German hyphenation patterns.  I invite everyone to participate and improve them!