# How to globally prevent hyphenation of a specific word in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, hyphenation

This question has been asked a few times for LaTeX (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74352/prevent-global-hyphenation-for-a-specific-word)) and I remember vaguely that I read somewhere that the technique is basically the same in ConTeXt. Alas, it doesn't seem to work too well.

In a nutshell: I would like to prevent hyphenation of specific words, say for proper names or brands. I know that I can use `\unhyphenated` for each instance, but I would rather prevent hyphenation of these words globally.

Using `\hyphenation` seems to be the method that is suggested most often, but it doesn't seem to work reliably. E.g. in the following MWE

```
\defineframedtext[secondary][
  frame=off,
  leftframe=on,
  framecolor=lightgray,
  rulethickness=6pt,
  offset=none,   % 0pt,
  loffset=6pt,
  indenting=no,
  align=flushleft,
  style=\em,
]

% ----------

\hyphenation{improvements largescale experiments}

% ----------

\starttext

\section{Testing hyphenation}

\startsecondary

\input{knuth}

\stopsecondary

\input{knuth}

\stoptext
```

...the command `\hyphenation` prevents the words *improvements* and *experiments* from being hyphenated (try commenting out the `\hyphenation{...}` command), but seems to have no effect at all on the word *largescale*:

[image: \hyphenation doesn't seem to work reliably]

I suspect that this might have something to do with the framedtext that I set up, but I can't quite put my finger on it. Can anybody help me understand, what I am missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: your output  shows that the word `largescale` is not in the source, it appears as `large-scale`  even in the wide text

Comment: Ah, thanks, I hadn't noticed that. Now, that explains the problem here – and makes my example a rather bad one. :) I chose `knuth` merely for this MWE, however, in the book that I'm typesetting this happens with quite a few words, such as *Tatjana*. Do I have to assume then that these words are rewritten (by some hyphenation algorithm somewhere) to contain hyphens...?

Comment: most likely you are specifying hyphenation rules for the wrong language. `\hyphenation` is the primitive, but in latex you would use babel to control laguage settings, context will have something equivalent but I do not know the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see `knuth.tex` (just the first paragraph):

```
Thus, I came to the conclusion that the designer of a new
system must not only be the implementer and first
large||scale user; the designer should also write the first
user manual.
```

That's how you specify a discretionary hyphen in ConTeXt, I guess.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I hadn't noticed that. So, I might add the question, how to override these discretionary hyphens... :)
Anyway, using `knuth.tex` was only an example (a bad one, as I now realize). I noticed that the algorithm is ignoring quite a few specific words in my own text, such as *Tatjana*. Does that mean that all of these words have discretionary hyphens defined somewhere...?

Comment: @MarcusC. Make an example showing the *real* issue in a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the meantime I found the root of the problem: I had used the `\hyphenation` command over and over hoping that would allow me to prevent further words from being hyphenated. As it turns out, this seems to have overridden previous definitions. I already posted another question regarding this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656832/how-to-use-the-hyphenation-command-in-context-to-add-further-definitions