# ConTeXt LMTX causes compilation error when using \lineheight

Tags: context, compilation-error, context-lmtx

Following up on [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656832/how-to-use-the-hyphenation-command-in-context-to-add-further-definitions), I recently installed the new *LMTX* version of *ConTeXt* (having worked with *MkIV* up to now) and found that this solved a few problems. However, the new version seems to dislike a few of my definitions that worked without any problems before. In particular, `\lineheight` seems to cause problems. The following MWE illustrates the problem:

```
\defineblank[extractdistance][0.5\lineheight]

\setupdelimitedtext[speech][
  style=\em,
  spacebefore=extractdistance,
  leftmargin=24pt,
  before={\setupindenting[no]},
]


\starttext

\section{Testing lineheight with ConTeXt LMTX}

\input{knuth}

\startspeech

\input{knuth}

\stopspeech

\stoptext
```

Upon compilation I get the following error message (I installed ConTeXt in `/opt/context`):

[image]

which, as far as I was able to determine, is caused by my usage of `\lineheight`. Can anybody offer an explanation as to what's wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `\defineblank` command passes its argument to Lua and can't handle a length value, you can either replace `\defineblank` with `\defineblankmethod` or expand the length with `\defineblank[extradistance][\the\dimexpr 0.5\lineheight\relax]`. A even simpler solution is to use the predefined `halfline` space (e.g. `spacebefore=halfline`).

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, that solved my problem. I'm wondering, what changed in the LMTX version to make this necessary, as the code worked without any problems before. Anyway, we can consider this solved.
Would you like to post this as an answer – rather than a comment – so that I can accept it?

Comment: @MarcusC. lmtx is a completely new engine, replacing luatex as the engine basis for context so "what changed" is "most things"

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCarlisle! That explains why the layout of another rather complex document (utilizing lots of custom floats and environments) that I'm working on now seems almost totally broken. It's a frustrating experience indeed to update to a more recent *ConTeXt* version to get rid of an old bug and subsequently having to re-work my old code...

Comment: The change regarding `\definablank` happened more than 6 years ago and even the high level interface (`\define...` and `\setup...`) hasn't changed a lot since then.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster: Thanks for the clarification. Though that might well be true, all I can say is that my MkIV code has been working well up to the recent update to LMTX. But, that can easily be changed, no problem. I'm now having a lot more problems related to page widths, header sizes, float positions, caption widths and so on. (I guess I will have to post new questions soonish.)

Comment: @MarcusC. You can always run `context --luatex ...` to use MkIV.

Comment: @Aditya: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, no, that doesn't seem possible. It was one of the first things I tried, but I keep receiving errors (`...not found`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create additional arguments for `\blank` command ConTeXt provides

- `\defineblank` and
- `\defineblankmethod`

The `\defineblank` command can be used to synonyms for existing argument, e.g.

```
\defineblank [extradistance] [halfline]
```

To create a space which relies and a TeX length you have to use the `\defineblankmethod` command, e.g.

```
\defineblankmethod [extradistance] [.5\lineheight]
```